# Scale ANSI art to match dimensions of terminal

Tags: python, ansi-escape

I'm trying to scale ANSI art to the dimensions of a terminal window. What I'm trying to do is recognize when an object exists in the image and scale it out, rather than scaling the entire image. I'm having some difficulty and would like some advice over what I have so far. I'm writing this in Python and was trying not to really use any external libraries but at this point I would go for one. I really can't figure out a good way to do this.

```
import os
import blessed
import re
import random

# ANSI code for the BBS-style header


ANSI_COLORS = [
    "\033[41m",  # Red
    "\033[42m",  # Green
    "\033[43m",  # Yellow
    "\033[44m",  # Blue
    "\033[45m",  # Magenta
    "\033[46m"   # Cyan
]


RESET_COLOR = "\033[0m"


main_menu = """""" # this was data dumped from an ansi file using xxd. 


terminal = blessed.Terminal()

def xxd_to_ansi(xxd_text):
    # Decode xxd_text to bytes
    ansi_bytes = bytes.fromhex(xxd_text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")) # Cleaning any spaces and newlines

    try:
        # Convert from CP437 to UTF-8 encoding
        utf8_text = ansi_bytes.decode('cp437')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # If there's an error, replace problematic characters
        utf8_text = ansi_bytes.decode('cp437', 'replace')

    return utf8_text


def find_option_positions(menu_screen, menu_options):
    positions = []
    lines = menu_screen
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        start = line.find("[")
        end = line.find("]")
        if start != -1 and end != -1 and len(positions) < len(menu_options):
            positions.append((i, start, end))
    return positions


def adjust_menu_option(option, available_length):
    """Adjust the length of the menu option to fit the available space."""
    if len(option) > available_length:
        # truncate the option if it's too long
        return option[:available_length]
    elif len(option) < available_length:
        # pad the option if it's too short
        return option + ' ' * (available_length - len(option))
    else:
        return option
        
def adjust_brackets(line, start, end, option_str_length):
    # We need to account for the 2 spaces for [ and ]
    while end - start - 2 < option_str_length and start > 0:
        start -= 1
    return start, end

# Generate a basic ANSI colored pattern
def generate_pattern(length):
    return ''.join([random.choice(ANSI_COLORS) + " " for _ in range(length)])

# Overlay logo on ANSI pattern
def overlay_logo_on_pattern(ansi_logo):
    # Split logo into lines
    lines = ansi_logo.split('\n')

    output = []
    for line in lines:
        new_line = []
        in_ansi_code = False

        i = 0
        while i < len(line):
            if line[i] == "\033":
                in_ansi_code = True
                new_line.append(line[i])
                i += 1
                continue
            
            if in_ansi_code and line[i] == "m":
                in_ansi_code = False
                new_line.append(line[i])
                i += 1
                continue
            
            if not in_ansi_code and line[i] == " ":
                new_line.append(generate_pattern(1))
            else:
                new_line.append(line[i])

            i += 1

        output.append(''.join(new_line) + RESET_COLOR)

    # Display the output
    return '\n'.join(output)
    
    
    
def is_inside(rows, y, x):
    return 0 <= y < len(rows) and 0 <= x < len(rows[y])

def identify_shapes(rows):
    visited = set()
    shapes = []

    for y in range(len(rows)):
        for x in range(len(rows[0])):
            if (y, x) not in visited and len(rows) > y and len(rows[y]) > x and rows[y][x] != ' ':
                shape = []
                to_explore = [(y, x)]
                while to_explore:
                    cy, cx = to_explore.pop()
                    if 0 <= cy < len(rows) and 0 <= cx < len(rows[0]) and (cy, cx) not in visited:
                        if (cy, cx) not in visited and len(rows) > cy and len(rows[cy]) > cx and rows[cy][cx] != ' ':
                            # rest of the code inside the if condition
                            current_ansi = rows[cy][cx]
                            visited.add((cy, cx))
                            shape.append(((cy, cx), current_ansi))  # Store position and ANSI value
                            for ny, nx in [(cy-1, cx), (cy+1, cx), (cy, cx-1), (cy, cx+1)]:
                                to_explore.append((ny, nx))
                if shape:
                    shapes.append(shape)

    return shapes


def scale_shapes(shapes, target_width, target_height):
    scaled_shapes = []
    for shape in shapes:
        min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y = [int(x) for x in bounding_box(shape)]
        width_ratio = target_width / (max_x - min_x + 1)
        height_ratio = target_height / (max_y - min_y + 1)

        scaled_shape = []
        for (y, x) in shape:
            scaled_shape.append((int((int(y[0]) - min_y) * height_ratio), int((int(x[0]) - min_x) * width_ratio))) #int(y[0]) and int(x[0]) are not right 

        scaled_shapes.append(scaled_shape)


    return scaled_shapes


def bounding_box(shape):
    coords = [(point[0], point[1]) for point in shape if isinstance(point[0], (int, float)) and isinstance(point[1], (int, float))]
    if not coords:
        return 0, 0, 0, 0  # default values, adjust as needed
    min_x = min(x for _, x in coords)
    max_x = max(x for _, x in coords)
    min_y = min(y for y, _ in coords)
    max_y = max(y for y, _ in coords)
    return min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y

def render_scaled_logo(rows, target_width, target_height):
    shapes = identify_shapes(rows)
    scaled_shapes = scale_shapes(shapes, target_width, target_height)

    grid = [[' ' for _ in range(target_width)] for _ in range(target_height)]
    for shape in scaled_shapes:
        for (y, x), ansi_value in shape:
            if 0 <= y < target_height and 0 <= x < target_width:
                grid[y][x] = ansi_value  # Use the original ANSI value

    return '\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in grid])


def scale_ansi_logo(logo, target_width, target_height):
    return render_scaled_logo(logo.split('\n'), target_width, target_height)

def get_terminal_size():
    """Retrieve terminal size."""
    rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
    return int(columns), int(rows)

#☠

def main():
    target_width, target_height = get_terminal_size()
    with terminal.fullscreen(), terminal.cbreak(), terminal.hidden_cursor():
        menu_screen = xxd_to_ansi(main_menu)
        menu_screen = '\n'.join([str(int(item)) for item in menu_screen if item.isdigit()])
        menu_screen = scale_ansi_logo(menu_screen, target_width, target_height)

        # Main menu options
        menu_options = [
            "Create a new post",
            "View all posts",
            "Create a new Piet program",
            "Run a Piet program",
            "Exit",  # Option to exit the program
        ]
        selected_option = 0

        positions = find_option_positions(menu_screen, menu_options)

        while True:
            # Show the menu screen with adjusted options
            print(terminal.clear())
            
            lines = menu_screen.split('\n')
            for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                if i in [pos[0] for pos in positions]:  # if this line contains an option
                    idx = [pos[0] for pos in positions].index(i)
                    if idx < len(menu_options):  # Make sure we don't go out of range

                        start, end = positions[idx][1], positions[idx][2]
                        
                        prefix = "☠ " if idx == selected_option else "  "
                        suffix = " ☠" if idx == selected_option else "  "
                        option_str = prefix + menu_options[idx] + suffix
                        
                        # Adjust the brackets if the option_str is too large
                        start, end = adjust_brackets(line, start, end, len(option_str))
                        
                        line = line[:start+1] + option_str + line[end:]
                print(line)

            key = terminal.inkey()
            if key == terminal.KEY_UP:
                selected_option = (selected_option - 1) % len(menu_options)
            elif key == terminal.KEY_DOWN:
                selected_option = (selected_option + 1) % len(menu_options)
            elif key in [terminal.KEY_ENTER, ' ']:
                # Implement actions based on selection...
                pass
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Update:
I found [this module](https://github.com/FHPythonUtils/AnsiToImg) which allows you to convert the ansi to an img. What if I converted it to an image, upscaled/downscaled, and then converted it back?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Perhaps explain which part of your code you believe isn't doing what you want; i.e., how the observed behavior differs from your expectations.